# NextJS Search Query URL with Debounce

Tags: url, next.js, state, debouncing, react-instantsearch

I want to implement a instant Search Field with a Debounce.
So when I stop typing (after 500ms), starts the Search, and the search query is now also in de url-param.
My Problem is, I need to sync the url-query and the Input Field, so when I stop typing, the search query goes in the url-query.
But for e.g. when I switch the page and go back (so the search is now in the url-query, but the input field is empty) i need, that the url-query goes in the input field.

The API request is with a GraphQL Search Variable.

edit:
[This is a Git-Gist for the existigin Code](https://gist.github.com/Thomas-Blakeney/b8cddb8043d33d4923c52c881ab17e13)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Shallow Rounting**

When you update the input field you also update the URL

```
router.push('/?search=yourQuery', undefined, { shallow: true })
```

Setting "shallow" to true, will update the URL without reloading the page.

You can see more information about Shallow here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

And to fix your problem when you go back, you can try with **useeffect** with no dependencies to update your input if the URL has some query.

Comment: My Problem is, I have a useEffect, for the Case, that the Input-State changes. This useEffect pushes the route. But when I now a useEffect have, that runs when the Route changes, the Search State pushes, I have a infinite loop.

PS: in my edited question is the code

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to `await` the `router.push` in the onChange event handler